# Tracking if event "B" fires after event "A"?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I've been trying to figure this out with the Event Flow report but my issue is that I don't care if event "A" is the first event fired in the session. I just need a way to count how many times event "A" fires followed by event "B". Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I would love it if I can make this a goal, but I'll take what I can get at this point.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this but it appears by creating a custom sequence segment seems to get me the data I need.